Oracle SQL migration script
I want to copy/migrate data within the same table
For one of the columns, the only thing is that the column name is being updated. so basically I want to migrate everything under USERID col to USERNAME col
While for the other column, the data is migrated based on a mapping as below
WHEN OLD_COL = 'Data 1' THEN 'DATA1'
WHEN OLD_COL = 'Data 2' THEN 'DATA2'

Apart from the above 2 things, rest of the columns data should stay as it is
Can I run a single migration script to achieve the above ?

ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN userid TO username;

UPDATE table_name
SET   old_col = REPLACE(UPPER(old_col), ' ')
WHERE old_col IN ('Data 1', 'Data 2');

or
UPDATE table_name
SET   old_col = CASE
                WHEN OLD_COL = 'Data 1' THEN 'DATA1'
                WHEN OLD_COL = 'Data 2' THEN 'DATA2'
                END
WHERE old_col IN ('Data 1', 'Data 2');

Note: Use a WHERE filter so you do not update other rows unnecessarily.
If you have the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name ( userid, old_col, value ) AS
  SELECT 'Alice', 'Data 1', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Beryl', 'Data 3', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Carol', 'Data 2', 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Debra', 'Data 1', 400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Emily', 'Data 4', 500 FROM DUAL;

Then after the modifications, the table contains:



USERNAME
OLD_COL
VALUE




Alice
DATA1
100


Beryl
Data 3
200


Carol
DATA2
300


Debra
DATA1
400


Emily
Data 4
500



fiddle
